# How to trigger a core dump for an application using python script on all platforms?

Tags: python, linux, windows, coredump

I have a python script that supports linux, windows and in the future mac OS.
I would like to run the application in the python script and then trigger a core dump from the process id.

It can be easily accomplished by invoking gcore on linux platform in python subprocess.
How do I do it on windows?
In the future, we need to support MacOSX as well.

What is the best way to do this?

May be using python is not the right approach.

We can use a shellscript and install cygwin on windows.
Are there any gcore equivalent  on windows?
or we should use a .bat file instead ?

But I want to have a common scripts or python scripts across all platforms if possible and do not want to maintain different scripts.

Comment: There's no such thing as "core dump" on MS Windows. As far as generating an exception on any platform, a division by zero should work.

Comment: You can create a dump file on Windows using the dbghelp.dll library that's distributed with Windows 7+ (for XP it's in the SDK debugging tools). You can use ctypes to call [`MiniDumpWriteDump`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360), e.g.  `from ctypes import *;` `dbghelp = WinDLL('dbghelp');` `dbghelp.MiniDumpWriteDump(c_void_p(-1), os.getpid(), msvcrt.get_osfhandle(dumpfile.fileno()), 0, None, None, None)`. Except this should really be done from a separate watchdog process. The dump file can be loaded in a debugger such as WinDbg or cdb, e.g. `cdb -z core.dmp`.